# Word for shaking elbows (Covid-19 pandemic)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, neologisms

The recent epidemic has made people change a few habits. We no longer shake hands and a few of us touch each other  elbows as an alternative practice.

Has this kind of salutation a proper name?

Answer (score 12):

It's called [***elbow bump***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_bump).

> **Elbow bump:** A gesture (usually of greeting or farewell) in which two people lightly tap their elbows together as an alternative to a handshake or embrace, esp. in order to reduce the risk of spreading or catching an infectious disease. **[[OED]](https://public.oed.com/updates/new-words-list-april-2020/)**

[image: elbow bump]

It's been shortened to ***elbump***.

According to [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/elbump):

> **Elbump (noun):** An act of briefly touching somebody's elbow with your own to greet them, done to avoid spreading disease through touching each other's hands.

Comment: Expect this gesture' to be added to next years' dictionaries.

Comment: @GWarner It's already in OED: "**Elbow bump:** a gesture (usually of greeting or farewell) in which two people lightly tap their elbows together as an alternative to a handshake or embrace, esp. in order to reduce the risk of spreading or catching an infectious disease." (Draft addition April 2020)

Comment: Ironically it falls foul of the minimum social distancing guidelines, anywhere between 1m and 2m (depending which country you live),  and worse of all,  no one is wearing a facemask. Fertile conditions for spreading COVID 19, if you ask me.